# Getting Firebase data of last 24 hours

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get Firebase data of the last 24 hours. Actually I have this query:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref().child("datos").child("pedidos").child("nuevos");
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use `orderByChild` method on the timestamp child (or what ever you use  store the time ), and `startAt` to get the data only that before 24 hours

```
let before24Hour = new Date().getTime() - (24 * 3600 * 1000);
firebase.database().ref().child('datos/pedidos/nuevos').orderByChild('time').startAt(before24Hour).on('value' , function(snap){
    console.log(snap.val());
});
```

Comment: How does this work in firebase 9?